# not able to create table with border

Tags: html, batch-file

I want to add gif files into a TABLE (HTML file) by using batch command, I am facing problem with below lines

```
set "table_start=^<table border='1'>"
set "table_one=^<tr^>^<th^>^Name^</th^>^<th^>^Remarks^</th^>^</tr^>"
```

when i edit the html file in notepad i don't see tags for table border and row one. 
Below is the complete code, can somebody help me on this?

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file_start=^<title^>^HTML Table Header GIRI^</title^>"
set "table_start=^<table border='1'>"
set "row_one=^<tr^>^<th^>^Name^</th^>^<th^>^Remarks^</th^>^</tr^>"
set "image_start=^<tr^>^<th^>^<IMG SRC=""
set ^"image_end="^>^</th^>^<th^>^Remarks^</th^>^</tr^>"
set "table_end=^</table^>"
set "file_end=^</BODY^>^</HTML^>"
set "file_name=Index.html"

>"%file_name%"  ( echo %USERNAME% %DATE%  %TIME%
echo %file_start%
for %%I in (*.gif) do echo %image_start%%%~fI%image_end% 

echo %file_end%
)

start %file_name%
```

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the right delimiter (greater-than sign) in the same way as the left one (as you had escaped all right delimiters in your code):

```
set "table_start=^<table border="1"^>"
                                   |
                                   Here!
```

Comment: when i edit the html file in notepad i don't see tags for table border.